# How to add an alert when trailing stop excecated?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Here is my code. How do I add an alert to track when trailing stop is hit?

```
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, comment="Long")
alert("TRL Long", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
strategy.exit("Exit","Long", trail_price = close[1], trail_offset = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

`strategy.exit()` has an argument called `alert_trailing` which you can use.

> ***alert_trailing (series string)*** Text that will replace the
> '{{strategy.order.alert_message}}' placeholder when one is used in the
> "Message" field of the "Create Alert" dialog. Only replaces the text
> if the exit was triggered by crossing `trail_offset` specifically.
> Optional. The default is na.

Comment: Is there anyway to add an alert to my strategy in this format alert("Exit", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)  and capture that alert_trailing?   
alert("Exit", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)

Comment: You need to calculate the trailing price yourself and check if the price touches that price. Then you can call your `alert()` function based on those conditions.